# What happens if I create a file while Time Machine is backing up?

Tags: time-machine

Will the file be saved onto my backup drive? Is there a possibility that I might corrupt my backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be saved if the containing folder has not yet been backed up, otherwise it will be backed up next time Time Machine makes a backup. The backup will not be corrupted.